# How do I fix "undefined reference" errors in my Qt-Creator project while linking the ffmpeg library "libav"?

Tags: c++, qt, video, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to use the libav library from FFmpeg in my Qt-Creator project, but I get over a thousand "undefined reference to ..." errors and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The errors don't depend on the actual code, because I changed it a few times, but as long as I use methods of the library these errors occur.
I have also tried to run the code in Visual Studio and that worked.

My project-file looks like this:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
INCLUDEPATH += D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\include

SOURCES += \
    Main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LIBS += -lMfuuid
LIBS += -lStrmiids
LIBS += -lMfplat
LIBS += -lBcrypt
LIBS += -lSecur32
LIBS += -lWs2_32
LIBS += -pthread
LIBS += -L"D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib"
LIBS += -lavdevice
LIBS += -lavfilter
LIBS += -lavformat
LIBS += -lavcodec
LIBS += -lswresample
LIBS += -lswscale
LIBS += -lavutil

HEADERS += \
    wrapper.h
```

The library files are stored at D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib. The errors I get when running the program look something like this (extract).

```
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/aviobuf.o):(.text$mn+0x16): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/aviobuf.o):(.xdata[$unwind$ff_read_string_to_bprint_overwrite]+0x1c): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/4xm.o):(.text$mn+0x250): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.text$mn+0x2fe): undefined reference to `sscanf'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.text$mn+0x33f): undefined reference to `sscanf'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.text$mn+0x65b): undefined reference to `__report_rangecheckfailure'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.text$mn+0x18): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.text$mn+0x97): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.text$mn+0x14d): undefined reference to `__report_rangecheckfailure'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.xdata[$unwind$yuv4_read_header]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/yuv4mpegdec.o):(.xdata[$unwind$yuv4_read_packet]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/xwma.o):(.text$mn+0x14): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
:-1: Fehler: D:\Programme\ffmpeg-source\ffmpeg-5.1.2\vs2019_build\lib/libavformat.a(libavformat/xwma.o):(.text$mn+0x2e0): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
...
```

Is a library missing? Am I including the lMfuuid, Strmiids, Mfplat, etc. the wrong way? If you have any idea I would be very grateful. I'm really confused. I'm using the MinGW64 compiler.

Comment: You seem to link C++ libraries from different compilers together as they have different ABIs underneath.

Comment: Are you using the visual studio compiler or gcc?

Comment: No library is missing, the problem is that you are mixing and matching libraries for different compilers. These are not compatible.